# Curl artifactory for latest artifact with artifact type

Tags: curl, artifactory

I would like to download a latest artifact from artifactory with extension ".war". so I am trying to curl artifactory to download latest version of artifact.

curl command that I am trying , `curl "https://artifactory.xxx.com/artifactory/api/search/pattern?pattern=bds-snapshot:com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/*.war"`

```
But the output of this curl is fetching all the artifacts as below
files: [
"com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20170818.13548-103.war",
"com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20171005.214754-171.war",
"com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20171120.213458-241.war",
"com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20170426.162605-4.war",
 "com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20170907.193242-118.war",
 "com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20170616.143453-34.war",
 "com/test/sample/mobile-project-api/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/mobile-project-api-0.0.1-20170803.221511-77.war",
 ]
}
```

can someone help me for downloading latest artifact using curl command in artifactory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this use, you have the "Retrieve Latest Artifact" endpoint:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

Comment: How would you retrieve the latest SNAPSHOT regardless of the version number? It seems as if Artifactory can either give you the file path to the latest RELEASE or the paths for a SNAPSHOT where you know the major/minor/hotfix numbers but it can't give you the path to the latest SNAPSHOT path if you don't know anything about the version numbers. Is that correct?

Comment: I've answered my own question ;) Currently you can't but there is a ticket for this here - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9666